# How to set evaluation criteria of Weka grid search through java code

Tags: java, classification, weka, document-classification

I need to set a evaluation criteria to Weka grid search through java code. I have added the following code. But it is not working.

```
    int EVALUATION_CC = 0;
    int EVALUATION_RMSE = 1;
    int EVALUATION_RRSE = 2;
    int EVALUATION_MAE = 3;
    int EVALUATION_RAE = 4;
    int EVALUATION_COMBINED = 5;
    int EVALUATION_ACC = 6;
    int EVALUATION_KAPPA = 7;    
    Tag[] TAGS_EVALUATION = {
        new Tag(EVALUATION_CC, "CC", "Correlation coefficient"),
        new Tag(EVALUATION_RMSE, "RMSE", "Root mean squared error"),
        new Tag(EVALUATION_RRSE, "RRSE", "Root relative squared error"),
        new Tag(EVALUATION_MAE, "MAE", "Mean absolute error"),
        new Tag(EVALUATION_RAE, "RAE", "Root absolute error"),
        new Tag(EVALUATION_COMBINED, "COMB", "Combined = (1-abs(CC)) + RRSE + RAE"),
        new Tag(EVALUATION_ACC, "ACC", "Accuracy"),
        new Tag(EVALUATION_KAPPA, "KAP", "Kappa")
    };
    SelectedTag st=new SelectedTag(EVALUATION_ACC, TAGS_EVALUATION);
    GridSearch gs = new GridSearch();
    gs.setEvaluation(st);
```

Can any one please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Can say what isn't working? Does it run? Are you getting an error? What does it do that you don't like?

Comment: it is running without an error. But still grid search uses its default evaluation criteria( CC- Correlation Coefficient)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this,

```
GridSearch gs = new GridSearch(); 
int requiredIndex = 6; // for accuracy
SelectedTag st=new SelectedTag(requiredIndex , weka.classifiers.meta.GridSearch.TAGS_EVALUATION);
gs.setEvaluation(st);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but eventually I got it to work, using this:

```
int waucIndex = 8;
SelectedTag st=new SelectedTag(waucIndex , weka.classifiers.meta.GridSearch.TAGS_EVALUATION);
search.setEvaluation(st);
```

You can verify that it's set correctly by doing:

```
System.out.println(search.getEvaluation());
```